# Next value from a set of strings using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

Can someone tell me how to get this output using bash script ?

Input1:

```
xyzaa97
xyzaa98
xyzaa99
```

Output:

```
xyzaa100
```

Input2:

```
abc01
abc02
```

Output:

```
abc03
```

Comment: Separate words and numbers from your input variables, add the next logical number using basic arithmetic and join them together.

Comment: How to get the index of the number in the string using bash script ?
Once I got the index , I will make substrings and do rest of the stuff myself.

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Post it and let us know how it failed

Comment: If you haven't tried this, just take a look at http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions , it should be pretty simple once you have a regex for it

Comment: Use `bash` shell to text processing gets cumbersome when it comes to large files, can you use text processing tools like `Awk`, `sed`?

Comment: I can use awk , sed , grep also. No problem in that. But I am unable to figure out how to get the index of the number in a string

Comment: Why people are downvoting it ? Is it not a good question ? I learnt so many things from this question and the answers you guys gave.

Comment: I didn't down vote but SO is not a code writing service and usually when one shows no effort to have figured out how to do what one is asking, it gets down voted.

Comment: I tried it for around 1 hour but unable to figure out how to get index of number in a string :(

Comment: Then next time, show some of the effort and you'll likely not get down voted. Also, have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you write a question that typically gets up votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bash:

```
# get last line of file
name=$(tail -n 1 file)

# split $name in two parts with regex to array BASH_REMATCH
if [[ $name =~ ([a-z]+0*)([0-9]+) ]]; then

  # increase right part, option -i to set integer flag
  declare -i num=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}+1

  # join again both parts together
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$num"
fi
```

With this file:

```
abc01
abc02
```

Output:

```
abc03
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, by seeing your statement to get the index I completely misunderstood your requirement, so here is what it could be in awk, let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'END{val=$0;sub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"",val);val++;sub(/[0-9]+/,val);print}'  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk 'END{val=$0;sub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"",val);sub(/[0-9]+/,++val);print}'  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** With my previous attempt with match also.

```
awk 'END{match($0,/.[^0-9]*/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) substr($0,RLENGTH+1)+1}' Input_file
```

Comment: previously I used match :), I added that suggestion now too.

Answer (score 2):

`gawk` using `match()`

```
awk 'END{match($0,/([A-Za-z])([0-9]+)$/,a); sub(a[2],sprintf("%02d",a[2]+1),$1); print $1}' infile
```

`non-gawk` using `split()`

```
awk 'END{split($1,a,/[^0-9]+/); sub(a[2],sprintf("%02d",a[2]+1),$1); print $1}' infile

# OR

awk 'END{t=$1;sub(/[^0-9]+/,"",t);sub(/[0-9]+/,sprintf("%02d",t+1),$1); print $1}' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat f
xyzaa97
xyzaa98
xyzaa99

$ awk 'END{split($1,a,/[^0-9]+/); sub(a[2],sprintf("%02d",a[2]+1),$1); print $1}' f
xyzaa100

$ cat f1
abc01
abc02

$ awk 'END{split($1,a,/[^0-9]+/); sub(a[2],sprintf("%02d",a[2]+1),$1); print $1}' f1
abc03
```

Comment: @Inian , added your suggestion along with other one using  `split()`, for a given input both will work, thank you.